# When i go to place orders through the backend of the magento site or front end the website crashes?

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

When I go to place order through the Admin Panel of the magento site or front end the website crashes and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /homepages/10/d569191818/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/Hilbri/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 393

Comment: can you please check the memory limit of your php server.?

Comment: i don't think memory issue, seems like it is going to for loop may be some third party module

Answer (score 0):

Increase your memory limit to **512M**. Try that and see if you still have issues.

In **PHP.ini**

> memory_limit 512M

In **.htaccess**

> php_value memory_limit 512M

**Note:** Don't forget to Restart service.